# feature extraction for stock prediction

Tags: python, dataset, prediction, feature-extraction

I got a dataset of 20 stocks values for each day - 60 days ago. those stocks affect the stock x I want to predict and I got the values of the stock x too. I would like to create a model to predict the stock x and test it with 10 cross-validation.
I'm looking for Features to extract from the data in order to create model.
any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Try being specific while asking question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a guide.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you use the following methods to perform feature selection to make an efficient model. I can't say which one is the best since it depends heavily on the dataset. You can easily find the implementations, literature, examples, etc over the internet if you give it a try.
Also, the choice of the models can vary since you haven't mentioned if you are trying a supervised scheme or unsupervised.

Unsupervised methods for feature selection:

- Laplace Score feature selection
- Spectral Feature selection
- GLSPFS feature selection
- JELSR feature selection
- PCA
- LDA
- Non-negative Matrix Factorisation
- SPEC family - Normalized Cut, ArbitraryClustering, FixedClustering
- Sparse clustering - Lasso
- Localized feature selection - LFSBSS algorithm
- Multi-Cluster Feature Selection
- Weighted K-means

However, if you are more interested in feature engineering only, then go for this library:
https://github.com/blue-yonder/tsfresh

Comment: 0


I mean which feature I will insert into the models For example STD or Variance might be possible to predict stock x with any model?